# For every row in a pandas dataframe, check if a column contains a string in in the last 5 rows

Tags: python, pandas

```
[Date]                  [Etype]        [IP]           [Device]   [Event]                  
1 2020-08-19 23:02:29    Daemon.Emerg  xx.xxx.xx.xx    True   CHASSIS-POWER_STATUS_FAILURE      
2 2020-08-19 23:03:57  Daemon.Warning  xx.xxx.xx.xx    True   CHASSIS-TIME_CHANGED_FORWARD     
3 2020-08-19 23:03:57    Daemon.Emerg  xx.xxx.xx.xx    True  NTPC-NTP_FIRST_SYNCH_ACHIEVED     
4 2020-08-19 23:04:13    Daemon.Alert  xx.xxx.xx.xx    True    CFM-CFM_SERVICE_FAULT_CLEAR      
5 2020-08-19 23:06:27  Daemon.Warning  xx.xxx.xx.xx    True         PORT-STATE_CHANGE__R_T
```

Above is a snippet of a dataframe I'm working with. What I want to do is for each row, check if the previous 5 series elements of the second column contain a string,
kind of like an FIFO list that moves down the column.

I would be happy if I could either get a 5 rows-long list that checked between datetime but the intervals are not uniform

```
df['Flag'] = df['Etype'].str.contains("Daemon.Emerg").between(current index datetime: 5 rows previous datetime)
```

I'm not sure how I would do this with index

Comment: Please clarify your question and example output.  First of all I assume the second column is Labeled 'Etype'.  Secondly, you state you want to check for a string but what you want to do is check for a given string such as "Daemon.Emerg".   I believe you want to set the 'Flag' column to True if the previous 5 rows contain the target string.  Why does your example  'Flag' column for row 1 contain True?  What does the 'Date' column have to do with anything?

Comment: @itprorh66 - "you want to do is check for a given string such as "Daemon.Emerg". I believe you want to set the 'Flag' column to True if the previous 5 rows contain the target string." Thats exactly what I want to do. I have edited the question to remove that last column as it was a previous flag I was using. The date column is a date-time stamp for each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked into pd.rolling and it seemed to fit my description. The following worked for me:

```
    df['Prev'] = [x.values.tolist()[:-1] for x in df['Etype'].rolling(N)]
    df['Prev5_flag'] = ciena_df['Prev'].str.contains("Daemon.Emerg", regex=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to use `shift` to get the previous nth row's etype. We have to do this multiple times to get the previous five rows. Then we join those results together as one column. It's a little hard to parse, but we can do this with list comprehension:

```
# shift then filter out any nan's that occur when prior row is unavailable,
# then use ', '.join() to combine results. 
# Use list comprehension to do this for each row and for each shift.

df['prev'] = [', '.join([str(df['[Etype]'].shift(i).values[j]) 
                         for i in range(1, 6) 
                         if str(df['[Date]'].shift(i).values[j]) != 'nan']) 
              for j in range(5)]
```

Then you can check for what you want using `df.prev.str.contains`